# fadeIn, fadeOut not working (or I don't know how to make it work)

Tags: jquery, fadein, fadeout

I have a div with the following class:

```
#instrucPanel {
    background-color:black;
    opacity:0;
    position: absolute;
    left: 180px;
    top: 71px;
    height: 226px
}
```

At page load is hidden. I want to display it when user click on a button. And make it hidden if the user click on the same button.

To do that I'm using the following JavaScript code:

```
function ShowHideInstruc()
{
    if ($.myNameSapace.instShown)
    {
        $.myNameSpace.instShown = false;
        $('#instrucPanel').fadeOut('fast');
    }
    else
    {
        $.myNameSpace.instShown = true;
        $('#instrucPanel').fadeIn('slow');
    }
}
```

But I don't see anything, it is always hidden.

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: opacity:0; wont work in every browser, but what happens when you run your function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you must use `display:none;` as opposed to `opacity:0`.

Then you can make use of the [`.fadeToggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/fadeToggle/) method, like this:

```
function ShowHideInstruc()
{
     var show = $.viacognitaspace.instShown = !$.viacognitaspace.instShown; 
     $('#instrucPanel').fadeToggle((show) ? 'fast' : 'slow');
}
```

Note how this approach is a whole lot DRYer.

Comment: Or just use `.fadeToggle()`. And I _think_ `visibility: hidden` works too, if you want the element to take up its space while being hidden.

Answer (score 1):

`opacity: 0;` makes your Panel transparent.

Use the `display: none;` to hide the panel at the beginning and then just fadein and fadeout with jQuery

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE** Here is the working demo of what you want on [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/codingfreak/TtN5P/1/)